# Google Classroom: Shared page title has encoding issues

Tags: google-classroom

When sharing a French page from my company's site on Google Classroom, the title (that has French accents in it) is displayed with an encoding issue.

See this image:

[image: Screenshot showing title encoding issue]

The page I'm sharing looks well-formed. Here it is: https://www.edumedia-sciences.com/fr/media/167-erosion-cotiere

Has anyone else experienced this?
Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: if you try to paste the same link to other web pages, facebook, etc, does it also happen? i'm thinking this doesnt have anything to do with classroom api

Comment: Well, if you paste that exact URL into https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator or https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ you'll see it is just fine. And this is why it bugs me :(

Answer (score 0):

It looks that Google Classroom is taking the link text from the title tag instead of the og:title property and it's not able to properly parse it.

This was already reported as bug --> [Parsed links don't display swedish characters](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67349503)

Star this issue to indicate that you are affected by this issue.